# ag-grid community server side filtering

Tags: angularjs, angular, frontend

My project is using ag-grid community version.
Does it support server side filter and paging? If not, how do we apply filtering for ag-grid community version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server side filter is an enterprise feature. For community version you can use the Infinite Row Model and you need to customize your API to get data chunk by chunk (using page and rowCount) and also with filter if exists.

You can go through this [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-infinite-scrolling/) and get a clear idea about how to use this feature.

Also you can get the row model(infinite, server side) comparisons [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-models/).